# How to create JPEG compressed DICOM dataset using pydicom?

Tags: python, jpeg, dicom, imaging, pydicom

I am trying to create a JPEG compressed DICOM image using [pydicom](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/). A nice source material about colorful DICOM images can be found [here](http://dicomiseasy.blogspot.com/2012/08/chapter-12-pixel-data.html), but it's mostly theory and C++. In the code example below I create a pale blue ellipsis inside `output-raw.dcm` (uncompressed) which looks fine like this:

[image: Sample DICOM image]

```python
import io
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from pydicom.dataset import Dataset
from pydicom.uid import generate_uid, JPEGExtended
from pydicom._storage_sopclass_uids import SecondaryCaptureImageStorage

WIDTH = 100
HEIGHT = 100


def ensure_even(stream):
    # Very important for some viewers
    if len(stream) % 2:
        return stream + b"\x00"
    return stream


def bob_ross_magic():
    image = Image.new("RGB", (WIDTH, HEIGHT), color="red")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    draw.rectangle([10, 10, 90, 90], fill="black")
    draw.ellipse([30, 20, 70, 80], fill="cyan")
    draw.text((11, 11), "Hello", fill=(255, 255, 0))
    return image


ds = Dataset()
ds.is_little_endian = True
ds.is_implicit_VR = True
ds.SOPClassUID = SecondaryCaptureImageStorage
ds.SOPInstanceUID = generate_uid()
ds.fix_meta_info()
ds.Modality = "OT"
ds.SamplesPerPixel = 3
ds.BitsAllocated = 8
ds.BitsStored = 8
ds.HighBit = 7
ds.PixelRepresentation = 0
ds.PhotometricInterpretation = "RGB"
ds.Rows = HEIGHT
ds.Columns = WIDTH

image = bob_ross_magic()
ds.PixelData = ensure_even(image.tobytes())

image.save("output.png")
ds.save_as("output-raw.dcm", write_like_original=False)  # File is OK

#
# Create compressed image
#
output = io.BytesIO()
image.save(output, format="JPEG")

ds.PixelData = ensure_even(output.getvalue())
ds.PhotometricInterpretation = "YBR_FULL_422"
ds.file_meta.TransferSyntaxUID = JPEGExtended

ds.save_as("output-jpeg.dcm", write_like_original=False)  # File is corrupt
```

At the very end I am trying to create compressed DICOM: I tried setting various transfer syntaxes, compressions with PIL, but no luck. I believe the generated DICOM file is corrupt. If I were to convert the raw DICOM file to JPEG compressed with gdcm-tools:

```
$ gdcmconv -J output-raw.dcm output-jpeg.dcm
```

By doing a `dcmdump` on this **converted file** we could see an interesting structure, which I don't know how to reproduce using pydicom:

```
$ dcmdump output-jpeg.dcm

# Dicom-File-Format

# Dicom-Meta-Information-Header
# Used TransferSyntax: Little Endian Explicit
(0002,0000) UL 240                                      #   4, 1 FileMetaInformationGroupLength
(0002,0001) OB 00\01                                    #   2, 1 FileMetaInformationVersion
(0002,0002) UI =SecondaryCaptureImageStorage            #  26, 1 MediaStorageSOPClassUID
(0002,0003) UI [1.2.826.0.1.3680043.8.498.57577581978474188964358168197934098358] #  64, 1 MediaStorageSOPInstanceUID
(0002,0010) UI =JPEGLossless:Non-hierarchical-1stOrderPrediction #  22, 1 TransferSyntaxUID
(0002,0012) UI [1.2.826.0.1.3680043.2.1143.107.104.103.115.2.8.4] #  48, 1 ImplementationClassUID
(0002,0013) SH [GDCM 2.8.4]                             #  10, 1 ImplementationVersionName
(0002,0016) AE [gdcmconv]                               #   8, 1 SourceApplicationEntityTitle

# Dicom-Data-Set
# Used TransferSyntax: JPEG Lossless, Non-hierarchical, 1st Order Prediction
...
... ### How to do the magic below?
...
(7fe0,0010) OB (PixelSequence #=2)                      # u/l, 1 PixelData
  (fffe,e000) pi (no value available)                     #   0, 1 Item
  (fffe,e000) pi ff\d8\ff\ee\00\0e\41\64\6f\62\65\00\64\00\00\00\00\00\ff\c3\00\11... # 4492, 1 Item
(fffe,e0dd) na (SequenceDelimitationItem)               #   0, 0 SequenceDelimitationItem
```

I tried to use pydicom's [encaps module](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/reference/encaps.html), but I think it's mostly for reading data, not writing. Anyone else have any ideas how to deal with this issue, how to create/encode these `PixelSequence`s? Would love to create JPEG compressed DICOMs in plain Python without running external tools.

Comment: Are you able to read the JPEG compressed image through PyDicom?

Comment: Yes of course I can decompress and read it. Of course, you need a few extra libraries installed, here's the possible combinations: https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/image_data_handlers.html

Comment: Did this use case every get resolved?  I'd love to see some documentation on it myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DICOM requires compressed *Pixel Data* be [encapsulated](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/sect_A.4.html) (see the tables especially). Once you have your compressed image data you can use the [encaps.encapsulate()](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/dev/reference/generated/pydicom.encaps.encapsulate.html#pydicom.encaps.encapsulate) method to create `bytes` suitable for use with *Pixel Data*:

```py
from pydicom.encaps import encapsulate

# encapsulate() requires a list of bytes, one item per frame
ds.PixelData = encapsulate([ensure_even(output.getvalue())])
# Need to set this flag to indicate the Pixel Data is compressed
ds['PixelData'].is_undefined_length = True  # Only needed for < v1.4
ds.PhotometricInterpretation = "YBR_FULL_422"
ds.file_meta.TransferSyntaxUID = JPEGExtended

ds.save_as("output-jpeg.dcm", write_like_original=False)
```

Comment: This works, but only for single frame jpeg.  Anyone know how to encode a multiframe jpeg?

Comment: Each frame needs to be encoded separately and then all the frames encapsulated with `encapsulate([frame1, frame2, ...])`

Answer (score 4):

Trying the solution from @scaramallion, with more detail looks to work:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import io

# set some parameters
num_frames = 4
img_size = 10

# Create a fake RGB dataset
random_image_array = (np.random.random((num_frames, img_size, img_size, 3))*255).astype('uint8')
# Convert to PIL
imlist = []
for i in range(num_frames):   # convert the multiframe image into RGB of single frames (Required for compression)
    imlist.append(Image.fromarray(tmp))

# Save the multipage tiff with jpeg compression
f = io.BytesIO()
        imlist[0].save(f, format='tiff', append_images=imlist[1:], save_all=True, compression='jpeg')
# The BytesIO object cursor is at the end of the object, so I need to tell it to go back to the front
f.seek(0)
img = Image.open(f)

# Get each one of the frames converted to even numbered bytes
img_byte_list = []
for i in range(num_frames):
    try:
        img.seek(i)
        with io.BytesIO() as output:
            img.save(output, format='jpeg')
            img_byte_list.append(output.getvalue())
    except EOFError:
         # Not enough frames in img
         break

ds.PixelData = encapsulate([x for x in img_byte_list])
ds['PixelData'].is_undefined_length = True
ds.is_implicit_VR = False
ds.LossyImageCompression = '01'
ds.LossyImageCompressionRatio = 10 # default jpeg
ds.LossyImageCompressionMethod = 'ISO_10918_1'
ds.file_meta.TransferSyntaxUID = '1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.51'

ds.save_as("output-jpeg.dcm", write_like_original=False)
```